# React-Virtualized using cellmeasurer with a maximum width?

Tags: react-virtualized

Is there any way to use react-virtualized's `CellMeasurer` with a maximum column width which then made the height expand?

For example, I may have an id field in column one of the grid. This would never grow too large, but I want to size it based on the largest value. Then in column two I have a text field that I am not too sure how large it will be. If it turns out that all of my current data set has a small value in column two, I'd like to size based on the largest value. If it happens to have some larger text (over a certain width) I'd like to use that maximum width, and then expand the row's height to accommodate the lines text.

From what I can see in the docs and code, this type of feature isn't supported. If this is the case, I think my best method would be implementing my own `CellMeasurer` with a slightly more complex `_measure` function. Does this sound like the proper course of action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this by adding a style constraint to your rendered cell. CellMeasurer just measures what the browser reports- and CSS controls the browser's max width.

React might freeze the style object too so use spread rather than directly modifying:

```
style={{
  ...style,
 maxWidth: 300
}}
```

Comment: Ahh ok my fault. I saw the warning from measuring both dimensions and registered it as something it didn't allow. Looks good now, thank you!

Comment: And thanks for creating the plugin and supporting it!

Comment: It's not optimal because it leads to greedily measuring a lot of content up front, so I warn about it. If you can avoid it you should. In your case I would advise considering a fixed cell width of 300 and just using dynamic heights- but it's your call. :)